# im getting records from 5.30 am in date wise filter, issue in the time zone

Tags: c#, datetime

i want to get the records with date wise report, but im getting the records from 5.30 am of the selected date.kind of time - utc

json response

```
{"timestamp":"2018-08-24T12:36:13.519Z","dataFrame":"AQAPAyoADwMqAA8BKiM="}
```

model

```
public DateTime timestamp { get; set; }
```

code

```
List<FeederPillar> Pirs = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<FeederPillar>>(responseString);
    Pirs = Pirs.Where(x.timestamp.Date >= fromDate.Date && x.timestamp.Date <= toDate.Date).ToList();
    foreach (var item in Pirs)
    {

        dataframe = item.dataFrame;
        byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(item.dataFrame.ToString());
        FeederPillar FeederModel = new FeederPillar();
        string updtime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(Convert.ToDateTime(item.timestamp), TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("India Standard Time")).ToString();
        FeederModel.datetime = Convert.ToDateTime(updtime).ToString(string.Format("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt"));

    }
```

Comment: what did you expect to get? did I overread this part ?

Comment: What is expected behavior here? We just see that you're not receiving what you want/expect, but don't know what is desired.

Comment: bocz when you save your record its taking timezone as UTC + 00 and indian standard time has UTC+ 5:30 so when you get record it giving you as an indain standard time zone as an your date + 5:30

Comment: in the first line of code there is an issue , there is no conversion to utc to ist.how to convert ist like the conversion in foreach loop

Comment: but its taking by default UTC 00. so when you save your data set your timezone to UTC + 5:30

Comment: or when you getting from db then make you timezone as UTC - 5:30

Comment: i cant change the rest api. i need to change in client side. im getting the date in utc format froom the json response

Comment: so when you deserialize your json set its date to UTC-5:30 then all problm gonna be solved, could you post your json sample with date

Comment: {"timestamp":"2018-08-24T12:36:13.519Z","dataFrame":"AQAPAyoADwMqAA8BKiM="}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179179/discussion-between-ershoaib-and-krishna-mohan).

Answer (score 0):

```
Pirs = Pirs.Where(TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(Convert.ToDateTime(x.timestamp), TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("India Standard Time")).Date >= fromDate.Date && TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(Convert.ToDateTime(x.timestamp), TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("India Standard Time")).Date <= toDate.Date)
                        .ToList();
```

Comment: Sorry but I think this is _not_ a good example of [self answering](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: may be its not a good example or code, but im getting the corect records.@SonerGönül. kindly modify if any better code

Comment: @GrantWinney i achived my solution with this code .